# Git automatic merge removed some files

Tags: git, merge

I have a repository history as in this image (taken from gitk):
[image: Git History]

Now, something strange happened:

Commit (a) and (b) have a common ancestor (currently marked line).

In commit (a) "Commit for flexible preamble", some files were added to the repository. The files can be found in the repo when looking at the source tree for this particular git-commit.

In commit (b) which is the merge commit, suddenly the files from (a) were removed from the repository.

The merging was automatically done by TortoiseGit after the pull operation.

Unfortunately, I cant figure out what happened here. What did the user do wrong such that the files were removed? Or is it normal that in this constellation the files are removed?

The files were still there after the first merge (blue and gray line on 2016-12-01 19:59:52).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the parents in commit `b` either removed these files or the files were not present in that parent. Git has two versions of reality. One version, stemming from commit `a`, is that some new files were added. The other version says that these files are not there. Only one version can be possible after the merge.  As to why Git chose the version where the files aren't there, if the main branch in the merge (i.e. the one into which another branch was being merged) did not contain these files then Git may have given its version of things preference.

In any case, you can simply add the files again by checking them out from the commit where they existed via:

```
git checkout <SHA-1> -- filename
```

Comment: Apparently, in the marked commit (before (a)) the files were not there (they were added in the commit afterwards). Shouldn't the merge in (b) then combine the changes from both branches (i.e. the red line and the grey->purple line). In the purple line some files were added, in the red lines some unrelated files were changed.

Comment: @MaximilianMatthé I have seen this sort of thing happen many times with Git.  Think of a merge as combining two stories.  Story one says a bunch of files are there.  Story two says no they are not there.  This needs to be reconciled.